# Pure JavaScript and SWAPI

Tags: javascript

A have a problem
I need to realize the output of the name of the planet and the characters
The derivation of the name of the planet is realized
In the derivation of characters, links to the API, but you need their names
How to combine all this?
Thank you very much in advance

This is my code

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Simple markers</title>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getStarWarsPlanets(progress, url = 'https://swapi.co/api/planets', planets = []) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200)  {
          throw `${response.status}: ${response.statusText}`;
        }
        response.json().then(data => { 
          planets = planets.concat(data.results);

          if(data.next) {
            progress && progress(planets);
            getStarWarsPlanets(progress, data.next, planets).then(resolve).catch(reject)
          } else {
            resolve(planets);
          }
        }).catch(reject);
    }).catch(reject));
}

function progressCallback(planets) {
}

getStarWarsPlanets(progressCallback)
  .then(planets => {
    document.writeln(planets.map(p => p.name))
 document.writeln(planets.map(p => p.residents))
  })
  .catch(console.error);
</script>
```